# Is there any way to list the services published through a CBPeripheralManager instance?

Tags: core-bluetooth

The macOS/iOS Bluetooth LE API class **CBPeripheralManager** has the method **add(CBMutableService)** for publishing a service, **remove(CBMutableService)** for stopping publishing a service, and **removeAllServices()** for stopping publication of all published services. The class **CBService** has a **peripheral** property for identifying the peripheral through which it is offered. But I am darned if I can see any way to find out what services are published, given a **CBPeripheralManager** instance. Is there really no way to do this?

Comment: Surely your app published the services. Why would you need to interrogate the peripheral for them?

Comment: My app *is* the peripheral. And while I can keep my own list of active services, I'm surprised that's not an existing property, assuming it's not and I'm not just missing something.